# formatting with optional "replacement fields" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, string-formatting, python-3.8

there is such a code:

```py
text = "{first}, {second}, {etc}"

print(text.format(first="1", etc="34.."))
```

when it is executed, I (expectedly) get a `KeyError`.
my question is this:
Is it possible to make formatting not affect `second`, but just leave `"{second}"`?
that is, in my case, I want to get: `1, {second}, 34..`

Suppose I don’t know in advance which field I will format, what then?

Comment: Do this to leave `{second}` unformatted: `str_ = "{first}, {{second}}, {etc}"`

Comment: @zvone, yes, it’s possible to do so, but what if I don’t know in advance what I want to leave and what not?

Comment: Well, then just specify `.format(second='{second}')` to format it in such way that it remains same as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a library to solve this problem: [pyformatting](https://pypi.org/project/pyformatting/).
Here is the solution to problem with pyformatting:

```py
>>> from pyformatting import optional_format
>>> text = "{first}, {second}, {etc}"
>>> optional_format(text, first="1", etc="34..")
'1, {second}, 34..'
```

The only problem is pyformatting doesn't support python 2. pyformatting supports python 3.1+
If i see any feedback on the need for 2.7 support i think i will add that support.